# how to pass data between screens using intent in MIT app inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I am a beginner in MIT app inventor tool. I am stuck on passing data between screens. I have searched a lot of time on the internet. I got lots of results using activity starter with intent, but how it is possible in MIT app inventor?

If in android we can pass data like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);

i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");

i.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");

startActivity(i);
```

by using bundle we get that data, but how it is possible in MIT app inventor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have 2 options to pass data between screens:

1. to use the [open another screen with start value](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/control.html#openscreenwithvalue) block
   example:
   [image]
   as you can see, a value also can be a list...
   then in the other screen you can get the data using the [get start value](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/control.html#getstartvalue) block
2. to use [TinyDB](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/storage.html#TinyDB)
   for example in Screen1 just store the data in TinyDB and read it again in Screen2

[see also this example](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/programming-with-app-inventor/w7PAggKauz8/aa2YHe5cTKIJ)